# How to disable ssl certificate and only used to forward traffic on port 443 in Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, iptables, nginx-config

Host A has https service **serviceA** and provides two IP for high availability。

> e.g. Bose [ip1:443] and [ip2:443] are routed to the **serviceA**.

Host B (do not has ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key) use Nginx proxy module to proxies the requests towards the actual **serviceA**.
How to simply forward 443 port traffic to **serviceA** without ssl verification?
Here is my config:

```
http {
  upstream backend {
    server [ip1]:443;
    server [ip2]:443;
  }

  server {
    listen       443;
    listen       [::]:443;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://backend;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: nginx is an _HTTP_ server.  If you want to forward raw TCP bytes, you should use something else.

Comment: Nginx can't do it?

Comment: *two IP for high availability* Why?  If Host B with the second IP is only to forward traffic to Host A, you have no high availability because if Host A is down, nothing works.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Actually we have two Host B, randomly forward traffic to one of the hosts by ECMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two theoretically possible ways to solve your issue:

1. [Nginx with ngx_stream_ssl_preread module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html)
2. [HAproxy (for balancing) -> proxy_protocol -> Nginx (with ssl certs)](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/)

Comment: Can iptables do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2002:xxxx:9a21::1/128 -i sit6to4vip -p tcp --dport 443 -m statistic --mode random --probability .5 -j DNAT --to-destination 2002:xxxx:f6ea::1
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2002:xxxx:9a21::1/128 -i sit6to4vip -p tcp --dport 443 -m statistic --mode random --probability .5 -j DNAT --to-destination 2002:xxxx:f6e9::1

ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2002:xxxx:f6ea::1/128 -o sit6to4vip -p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 2002:xxxx:9a21::1
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2002:xxxx:f6e9::1/128 -o sit6to4vip -p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 2002:xxxx:9a21::1
```

It does't work